# How to change a rectangle's area based on it's coordinates?

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm developing an Android app. I have a polygon/rectangle with it's 4 bounds/coordinates on a Google Map. I have a variable named `areaDifference` which is set to an arbitrary value. I need to take the value of this variable and change the size of the rectangle. For instance, if `areaDifference` is set to 2, I need to make the rectangle twice as big. How do i change the size? I only have the 4 coordinates and the area variable.

Answer (score 0):

Just convert LatLon coordinates of your polygon/rectangle to screen coordinates, multiply screen coords by `areaDifference` and convert it back to LatLon. Something like that:

```
Polygon polygon = mGoogleMap.addPolygon(new PolygonOptions()
.add(new LatLng(0, 0), new LatLng(0, 1), new LatLng(1, 1), new LatLng(1, 0))
.strokeColor(Color.RED)
.fillColor(Color.GREEN));

List<LatLng> points = polygon.getPoints();
List<LatLng> scaledPoints = new ArrayList(points.size());

Projection projection = mGoogleMap.getProjection();
for (int i=0; i<points.size(); i++) {
    Point screenPosition = projection.toScreenLocation(points.get(i));
    screenPosition.x = areaDifference * screenPosition.x;
    screenPosition.y = areaDifference * screenPosition.y;
    LatLng latLng = projection.fromScreenLocation(screenPosition);
    scaledPoints.add(latLng);
}
polygon.setPoints(scaledPoints);
```

More details about scaling [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scaling_(geometry)).

**UPDATE:**

For scaling around center of polygon you should implement some more affine transformations: convert LatLon coordinates of your polygon/rectangle to screen coordinates, move center of polygon to screen cootds (0,0), multiply screen coords by `areaDifference`, move center of polygon to it's original point and convert it back to LatLon. You can use than methods to do that:

```
private static List<LatLng> scalePolygonPoints(List<LatLng> points, float scale, Projection projection) {
    List<LatLng> scaledPoints = new ArrayList(points.size());

    LatLng polygonCenter = getPolygonCenterPoint(points);
    Point centerPoint = projection.toScreenLocation(polygonCenter);

    for (int i=0; i < points.size(); i++) {
        Point screenPosition = projection.toScreenLocation(points.get(i));
        screenPosition.x = (int) (scale * (screenPosition.x - centerPoint.x) + centerPoint.x);
        screenPosition.y = (int) (scale * (screenPosition.y - centerPoint.y) + centerPoint.y);
        LatLng latLng = projection.fromScreenLocation(screenPosition);
        scaledPoints.add(latLng);
    }

    return scaledPoints;
}

private static LatLng getPolygonCenterPoint(List<LatLng> polygonPointsList){
    LatLng centerLatLng = null;
    LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
    for(int i = 0; i < polygonPointsList.size() ; i++) {
        builder.include(polygonPointsList.get(i));
    }
    LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();
    centerLatLng =  bounds.getCenter();
    return centerLatLng;
}
```

Usage:

```
...
areaDifference = 2.0f;
Projection projection = mGoogleMap.getProjection();
List<LatLng> scaledPoints = scalePolygonPoints(mPolygon.getPoints(), areaDifference, projection);
mPolygon.setPoints(scaledPoints);
...
```

Comment: It kinda works but it moves the rectangle as well. How can i resize around the center of the rectangle?